# I cant find the icon that is placed in maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, google-maps

I have a website.

> http://shipm8.ship2you.co/contactus

I have to change the icon that is appearing on the map, but I don't know where that icon is located.Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you have access to all files or just WP Dashboard? Basicly custom markers are set in JS init file for google map.
Here is documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Comment: `view-source->main.js->http://shipm8.ship2you.co/images/marker.png`

Comment: @Tpojka thanks allot. How did you get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view-source->main.js->http://shipm8.ship2you.co/images/marke‌​r.png`

When you check page source (right click-> view source), you should find image URL there. If you can's see it, itis most likely it is served by JS from some file. My assumption was to check custom (not known library seen there) file and first one to check was main.js file. In that file you would search for block of code that is responsible for google map. Actually first logic thinking for you should be to check google map code - where is called, calculated, executed... So there you can follow URL for marker. I noticed it is relative URL and just being appended to base url it showed image as well.